# Download a file and scroll to bottom div on button click

Tags: buttons

On button click, I want user to download a file which is an apk file.  On that same click, at the same time, I want to scroll to a div.

Is it possible to add two actions in a button?
Note: I'm using elementor.

Answer (score 2):

Demo:  https://codepen.io/livehelp/pen/MWoNPqX?editors=1010

Just use an HTML or Code element in Elementor to paste in the code instead of a Button element.

```
<h2><a href="#smooth" onclick="window.open('https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/apk-downloader.zip')";>Click to Download + Smooth Scroll</a></h2>

<p>Insert enough text here to have a scoll bar.</p>

<div id="smooth"><h1>Tadaa! Jumps to this div based on the id #smooth onClick.<h1></div>

<script>
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = this.getAttribute("href");
  const offsetTop = document.querySelector(href).offsetTop;

  scroll({
    top: offsetTop,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Rup Sorry about that. Done. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('.download-btn').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $('body').height() }, 800);
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code but its not working as expected. Added download-btn to class name of button and added the code you provided.